# Почему не отображаются Яндекс Карты на сайте?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Пишу сайт-приглашение на свадьбу, используя готовый проект https://github.com/rampatra/wedding-website. В оригинале используются Гугл Карты, но я хотел бы Яндекс. Изменив код на тот, который должен вызывать непосредственно карты Яндекса, наблюдаю, что они не отображаются. Уже много чего перепробовал, но так и не смог добиться желаемого результата. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Куски кода, которые загружают API карт и заполняют сегмент сайта, **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

...

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=***********&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;

    ymaps.ready(function() {
        map = new ymaps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
            center: [***,***],
            zoom: 16,
            controls: ['routeButtonControl', 'geolocationControl']
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

        marker = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [***,***]
            }
        });

        map.geoObjects.add(marker);
        )
    });
    </script>

...

<section id="map" class="section-padding">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Место проведения</h3>
        <!--<p>It's way easier than you think!</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

...
```

Кусок стилей под карту, **styles.min.css**:

```
#map-canvas{height:500px;width:100%}
```

Также прикладываю вырезанный ножницами а-ля скриншот сайта

[image: На фоне "Место Проведения" должны быть карты, но их нет...]

Comment: Добавлю, что на фоне элементов "Место Проведения" , "Для уточнения" и "Показать Карту" должна отображаться карта, но ее нет

Comment: Открой консоль в браузере и смотри что там не так.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо! Не додумался сначала. Оказывается, была лишняя скобка вот здесь:

        map.geoObjects.add(marker);
        )

Answer (score 1):

Причина проблемы супер-простая - невнимательность.
Была лишняя скобка:

```
        map.geoObjects.add(marker);
        )
```

В моем случае правильный вариант этих кусков файла:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

...

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=***********&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;

    ymaps.ready(function() {
        map = new ymaps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
            center: [***,***],
            zoom: 16,
            controls: ['routeButtonControl', 'geolocationControl']
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

        marker = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [***,***]
            }
        });

        map.geoObjects.add(marker);
    });
    </script>

...

<section id="map" class="section-padding">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Место проведения</h3>
        <!--<p>It's way easier than you think!</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

...
```